# Firestore Query Security Rules with resource.data returns false

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

```
match /User/{uid} {
            allow get : if request.auth.uid != null;
            allow list: if request.auth.uid != null  
            && ( request.time - resource.data.online ) < duration.value(24, 'h') &&
            request.query.limit <= 40 && request.query.orderBy['online'] == 'DESC'   ;

}
```

This is the rule for querying the list of users , the criteria is that it only needed to list User Documents having an online field less than 24 hour from now . The collection has user data with online field all less than 24 hours . But it returns false when querying from firebase-android-sdk using get() method . When removing the below condition it works but I am confused what's the issue with it .

```
( request.time - resource.data.online ) < duration.value(24, 'h')
```

I tried using `duration.abs(request.time - resource.data.online ) < duration.value(24, 'h')` too

In Android Client the code is

```
mQuery = mUsersDatabase.orderBy("online", Query.Direction.DESCENDING).limit(10);
mQuery.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                   ....
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to also show the code that performs the query?

Comment: It seems correct to me, maybe `resource.data.online` is the wrong type? Also check [this Medium post](https://medium.com/@khreniak/advanced-examples-of-using-cloud-firestore-security-rules-9e641d023c7e) as it has some other examples where they convert the time to millis before comparing (although it shouldn't be necessary).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I have added the android client that performs query

Comment: @Ajordat In Medium post itself , there are [Responses](https://medium.com/p/9e641d023c7e/responses/show) which shows its not working somehow

Answer (score 0):

**Rules on their own don't filter data. Instead, they merely enforce that all access to the data is authorized.**

If you want to only allow users to access data that is less than 24 hours old, you'll need two things:

1. A query that only reads data that is less than 24 hours old.
2. Security rules that allow that query, and reject other list operations.

Right now, you only seem to have the rules, and those correctly reject the query your code sends, as that query is trying to read all data.

You'll need to add a condition to the query to only request data that your rules allow. Something like:

```
mUsersDatabase
  .orderBy("online", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
  .where("online", "<", new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() - (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000))
  .limit(10)
```

You might need to tweak the offset a bit, to prevent a slight offset between client and server causing an unwanted rejection by the rules.

Comment: I tried it and the query is even returning false as the below log shows up . I used whereGreaterThan( ) in android-sdk                                                                                                                                   Listen for Query(target=Query(User where online > # com.google.firestore.v1.Value@f8de0f10
    integer_value: 0
    timestamp_value {
      nanos: 900000000
      seconds: 1590258878
    } order by -online, -__name__);limitType=LIMIT_TO_FIRST) failed: Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=Missing or insufficient permissions., cause=null}

Comment: Is there any other way to limit the query for clients  , as my aim is to secure from 
querying all users data in the db by restricting them to access users list that are having online > This time - 24 hours

Comment: When doing @FrankvanPuffelen's query did you remove the rules about time? The where condition is supposed to cover for the time filtering.

Comment: @Ajordat I didn't remove the rules its same as above

Comment: Then remove the time condition on the Firesbase Rules and perform the query that Frank provided.

Comment: @Ajordat But my objective is to have these restrictions for security reasons . Is there any way to meet this security criteria ?

Comment: I see. Is it possible that the condition should be inverted? If the order is descending and you want the documents with an `online` value of the last 24h, I believe it should be a `>` comparison. Also, have you tried adjusting the time offset that Frank mentioned? Try subtracting a minute less to compensate for network delays.

Comment: @Ajordat I tried the inverted condition before itself . Let me check the offset too